# Cannot serialize ISession when using Newtonsoft.Json library

Tags: c#, json.net, asp.net-core-3.0

my program is displaying the following error when trying to save some data without saving it to database and displaying it in json.

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: 'Could not create an instance of type Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.ISession. Type is an interface or abstract class and cannot be instantiated. Path 'Session.IsAvailable', line 1, position 26.'

[My Error Pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LpQNw.jpg)

This code is written using a repository design template.
The code written in the comment works.  Should I change the code `GetJson<T>` in the new version? after change using `Newtonsoft.Json` TO using `System.Text.Json.Serialization`?

```
public class CartController : Controller
{
    private  IProductRepository repository;
    private Cart _cart;
    public CartController(IProductRepository repo, Cart cart)
    {
        repository = repo;
        _cart = cart;
    }

    public ViewResult Index(string returnurl)
    {
        ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnurl;
        //return View(GetCart());
        return View(_cart);

    }
    public IActionResult AddToCart(int ProductID,string returnUrl)
    {
        Product product = repository.GetById(ProductID);
        if (product != null)
        {
            //Cart cart = GetCart();
            //cart.AddItem(product, 1);
            //SaveCart(cart);
            _cart.AddItem(product, 1);
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index", new { returnUrl });
    }
    public IActionResult RemoveFromCart(int ProductID, string returnUrl)
    {
        Product product = repository.GetById(ProductID);
        if (product != null)
        {
            //Cart cart = GetCart(); //-----> Worked
            //cart.RemoveLine(product); //-----> Worked
            //SaveCart(cart); //-----> Worked
            _cart.RemoveLine(product); //Not Working
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index", new { returnUrl });
    }
    //private Cart GetCart() //-->Worked
    //{
    //    Cart cart = HttpContext.Session.GetJson<Cart>("Cart") ?? new Cart();
    //    return cart;
    //}
    //private void SaveCart(Cart cart) //-->Worked
    //{
    //    HttpContext.Session.SetJson("Cart", cart);
    //}
}



 public static class SessionExtensions
{

    public static void SetJson(this ISession session, string key, object value)
    {
        session.SetString(key, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value));
    }
    public static T GetJson<T>(this ISession session, string key)
    {

        var value = session.GetString(key);

        return value == null ? default(T) :
            JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(value); //error exception throw here
    }

}
```

and:

```
     public  class SessionCart : Cart
      {
       public static Cart GetCart(IServiceProvider services)
       {

        ISession session = services.GetRequiredService<IHttpContextAccessor>()?.HttpContext.Session;
        SessionCart cart = session?.GetJson<SessionCart>("Cart") ?? new SessionCart();
        cart.Session = session;
        return cart;
    }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public ISession Session { get; set; }
    public override void AddItem(Product product, int quantity)
    {
        base.AddItem(product, quantity);
        Session.SetJson("Cart", this);
    }
    public override void RemoveLine(Product product)
    {
        base.RemoveLine(product);
        Session.SetJson("Cart", this);
    }
    public override void Clear()
    {
        base.Clear();
        Session.Remove("Cart");
    }
}
```

Comment: Need code of Cart.RemoveLine(...) for more details.

Comment: @AlexanderGoldabin all code is here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59751413/i-writing-a-shop-in-net-core-3-and-i-try-to-use-session-for-save-cart-items-b)

Comment: You previous question was closed. This one will be too for the same reasons.

Comment: @IanKemp If you can't fix the problem please let others help.

Comment: Why do you need the Session Property in your SessionCart class? Why not make it a private field?

Comment: Also you are not showing the code that calls GetJson

Comment: @Darkonekt GetJson Code Updating.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean what is clear to me is that you do NOT need the Session property in the SessionCart class... You can make this a private field and just pass in the reference in a constructor... If you make it a private field it will never get serialized to Json which will solve your exception.  The problem you have is that Json serializer cannot create an instance of an interface.

Comment: @lanKemp hi The problem was solved

Answer (score 1):

you must remove `system.Text.Json.Serialization`
and add `using Newtonsoft.Json` in `SessionCart`

Answer (score 0):

Just add the following namespace to the SessionCart class.

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
```

Answer (score 0):

I see you are following the Pro ASP.NET Core 2 MVC book by Adam Freeman.

To fix this issue, change the access modifier on the `ISession` variable from `public` to `private`. This will prevent the ISession being serialized and will then deserialize as you would expect.

Before:

```
 [JsonIgnore]
 public ISession Session { get; set; }
```

After:

```
 private ISession session { get; set; }
```

Then ensure all of your methods can use the lowercase `session` (to follow naming convention best practice).